# Proper noun dictionary?

Tags: dictionary

I did a search on dictionary.com for proper nouns and noticed it does not contain proper nouns.

Examples of words I was looking for was Camry and Camaro.

Is there a dictionary that does such?

Comment: You might be able to ask this at ELU SE.  I'm not sure.